# How to change DartPad UI?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way I can change the UI of [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) from Dark to Light or vice-versa?
I didn't find any button on the DartPad to do so.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no lightmode for [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/), even though there are some [requests](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/1643).
Also see [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/1150) issue.

Comment: But you'll find the light DartPad in their [code samples](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet)

Comment: Here https://dart.dev/resources/dartpad-best-practices you can find `Also, we adopted the light DartPad theme for demos and the dark DartPad theme for exercises.`

Comment: They just made this themes for visual distinguishing between examples and exercises.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I'll accept the answer in 4 some mins.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed the chrome extension 'Invert!' which worked.  Not wonderful colouring but better than black for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they support specifying a theme when embedding via `iframe`.

So if you want light theme, you can create local `dartpad.html` (or whatever .html) file and place this code into it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        iframe {
            display: block;
            border: none;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://dartpad.dev/embed-dart.html?theme=light"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I also placed the same file to GitHub Pages, so you just can use this link: https://ivanzoid.github.io/dartpad-light/